# unable to get jquery clone to work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the js code that i have currently

```
<script src="jquery.js type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input.clone').live('click', function(){
   //put jquery this context into a var
   var $btn = $(this);
   //use .closest() to navigate from the buttno to the closest row and clone it
   var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone();
   //append the cloned row to end of the table

   //clean ids if you need to
   $clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each( function(){
       //clear id or change to something else
       this.id += '_clone';
   });

   //finally append new row to end of table
   $btn.closest('tbody').append( $clonedRow );
});
</script>
```

below this, i have my table, with the clone button at the end of that table, its named and ID'd as clone.

When i click it nothing happens.

Comment: nothing happens. Do i need to add some kind of onclick action to my clone button?

Comment: I mean, if you put alert("hello") in the .live function, when you click it do you see the alert?

Comment: It works fine in my test: http://www.srcf.ucam.org/~rjeq2/test.html

Are you getting any errors in the error console?

Comment: you're missing a " for the src attribute of the jQuery script tag element. If this is a straight copy/paste that could be the problem

Comment: Ok it works fine. SOLUTION = didnt assign class of "clone" to the button. Of course i didnt know i had to, but now i do. Thanks all, and thanks Rodrido for your example, wouldnt have found it otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you told yourself, you had to assign the class clone to the button for the selector

```
$('input.clone')
```

to work.

had you used

`$('input#clone')` or even better `$('#clone')`

that would have worked for you, since  you said so yourself you ID'd it as clone.

Comment: yeah no problem, bit by bit you'll get to know jquery :)
just remember that the selectors work alot like css,  '.' for classes, '#' for ID's etc...